# ASP.NET - Return content

Tags: ms-access, vba, download

I have this situation. I need to, programatically, from VBA, return the content sent to me by the server in aspx format. It's image. I tried to access it via Temporary Files, but it only gives me the URL.

Please, help me, I'm in a hurry!!!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is you are asking for.

Comment: @vcsjones When I enter the page, it's an aspx page. It returns an image as the page content. I need to download that image. Like this: http://www.consignado.planejamento.rj.gov.br/CACaptchaAleatorio.aspx

Comment: @vcsjones "...not entirely..."? I do not have a single clue what is being asked :-)

Comment: If you're in a hurry, then perhaps it would help to better explain yourself, since nobody seems to understand what you want.

Comment: If you you want to do is download a file with VBA, this seems like a reasonable article complete with downloadable code: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DownloadFile.aspx

Comment: @MystereMan I will try to elaborate more. There's this page (the one in the link above), which my browser displays as an image in a blank document. If I download the page, it returns as .aspx. So I need to, somehow, download only the image. I can do this by right-clicking it and choosing "Save Image As". The problem is that I can only do this from VBA, or JavaScript, for my application rules say so. I hope I made it clear. Sorry.

Comment: @PatrickVillela - i'm still confused by how you are planning to run this code?  You say in the tags that it's for asp.net, but you talka bout vba, which isn't an asp.net language or a client-side language.  Are you writing a standalone app or script?

Comment: @vcsjones This article is perfect, but it only works if I know the exact url of the file, which I don't. The image is displayed by the aspx located on the server. I assume there's a way to get it, because my browser displays it.

Comment: @MystereMan I'm writing a VBA program that needs to download an image sent from the server by the aspx.

Comment: @PatrickVillela - What kind of VBA program?  in Office?  Which app?  As a stand-alone script run by wsh?  There's no such thing as a "vba program", vba is a scripting language that must be hosted in something else.

Comment: @MystereMan It's an Access Application. I put the tag wrong. It was supposed to be vba-access.

Answer (score 3):

Well, now that we don't have to read your mind anymore, it helps to understand what you're trying to do.

In all reality, that url *DOES* download the image.  It just has an aspx extension.  Rename it to .jpg and you can view it.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it didn't work. Neither manually, whenever I rename the file and open it, it doesn't show. What's strange is that it works in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @PatrickVillela - Yes, it does.  You can't save the document in IE because it's not a document.  It's an image.  If you try to save the document in IE it will corrupt the image because it's trying to save it as an html file.  Use the code provided by vcsjones to download the image, but save it with a filename ending in .jpg instead of .aspx

Comment: Oh, I see! I'm gonna try this.